# How to do load test for grpc services, Any sample code will be appreciated

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I am having trouble load testing gRPC services. Is there any way or tool to do that?

I tired Jmeter but looks like it does not support.

```
{
  "space_id": "3e9202b2-6d65-4651-96e5-af80ce51df70",
  "external_id": "5678",
  "anonymous": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are few existing load testing tools by community such as [ghz.sh](https://ghz.sh/).